# Can you cook raw meat in The Witcher 3

Tags: the-witcher-3

During the game, I found some "Raw Meat", and I want to know if it is possible to cook it to increase its "healing" time.

Comment: Googling "witcher 3 raw meat" returns a whole page of results all saying the same thing: no, you can't.

Comment: If you are playing on PC there seems to be a mod available to do so

Comment: Nope, I'm playing in ps4 . ^^

Comment: In the Gothic series, you usually can do that.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The only things you can do with food items is consume them or sell them to suitable merchants. Cooking isn't something that you can do.

Comment: Furthermore, there's no reason to do so -- Witcher's are practically immune to disease. (Maybe entirely?) You think Raw Meat's the worst thing Geralt's had to eat in his time?

Comment: @SableDreamer: Geralt still has a sense of taste, if he has the time, I am sure he would at least roast it. Especially in tousaint with some nice whine marinade or so

Comment: I know that Witcher's are immune to a lot of disease, (I read the books), But the question come, because, usually a raw meat healts, for example, during 5 sec, but if is cooked, it heals along 10 secs. So, If in W3 is possible (know I now, that is not), to cook will be better than eat raw meat